# Multi module Maven project- modules can't see each other

Tags: java, xml, maven, intellij-idea, multi-module

I have a simple Maven project, looking like this
[project view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGOcs.jpg)

There is a main pom.xml looking like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>piche</artifactId>
    <name>PICHE project</name>
    <description>PICHE project</description>
    <groupId>com.pesho.piche</groupId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <cucumber.jvm.version>1.2.5</cucumber.jvm.version>
        <project.version>1.0</project.version>
        <runner.folder>".."</runner.folder>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pesho.piche</groupId>
            <artifactId>test</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pesho.piche</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.jvm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.jvm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-guice</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.jvm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>${cucumber.jvm.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-assistedinject</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>22.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <modules>
        <module>core</module>
        <module>test</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

There are two modules- core and test.
core module pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>core</artifactId>
    <name>Core module</name>
    <description>Core Module</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.pesho.piche</groupId>
        <artifactId>piche</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>22.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

test module pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>test</artifactId>
    <name>Test module</name>

    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <parent>
        <artifactId>piche</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.pesho.piche</groupId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.pesho.piche</groupId>
            <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-guice</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice-assistedinject</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I want to use code from core inside test. The dependency looks right. The project is build with no errors:

```
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] PICHE project ..................................... SUCCESS [0.317s]
[INFO] Core module ....................................... SUCCESS [1.317s]
[INFO] Test module ....................................... SUCCESS [0.669s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.461s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jun 23 11:03:18 EEST 2017
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/41M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

But when I try to import a class from core in my tests, the class cannot be found.

Comment: You make sure that, your are accessing public classes from Core project.

Comment: Your dependency management is correct. Try building from command line, if it works, click on the re-import in the maven projects window in intellij.

Answer (score 0):

You Must make the version of **core dependency**  in your **test module pom** like this

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pesho.piche</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>${parent.version}</version> <!-- TODO -->
    </dependency>
```

**AND** delete thoes lines in your parent POM

```
<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pesho.piche</groupId>
        <artifactId>test</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.pesho.piche</groupId>
        <artifactId>core</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**AND** from your parent module :

```
mvn clean install
```

I hope that will help you

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the dependencies of `core` and `test` in parent `pom.xml` is unnecesary. To access the api in core, you just need to define the dependency in you pom and install it to local repository.
Run `mvn clean install` under the root directory of `core`, this will compile this project and package and install the `jar` to maven local repository. Then the dependency can meet in another project and you can access the api defined.
But any changes in `core` may lead you to reinstall it to local repository.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all your answers. I noted the suggestions. The problem was that I was using default packages in the modules. Never do that! Dependencies were OK but I couldn't see them because of the classpath options.